# Multiple developer work one storyboard in iOS

Tags: ios, git, storyboard

Multiple developers are working on one project using `Git`. However, multiple developers are not working at the same time on the same `storyboard`.

Currently we found out one solution :

Create a `storyboard` particular to a `UIViewController` like xib.

If this is not right way then suggest me which way is best?

Memory leak accord when i use multiple storyboard for separate VC?

Comment: We use the almost the same way: one storyboard for separate part of flow (3-4 VC).

Comment: Memory leak accord when i use multiple storyboard for separate VC .

Answer (score 0):

It really depends on how complex your views/storyboards are.

You could have 1 storyboard, which has multiple `UIViewController`s, and multiple folks can work on different view controllers, with low chance of conflicts. You could have one storyboard for each view controller, but IMO you don't have to. Our project sometimes have almost ten `UIViewController`s in one storyboard, and things are fine.

My two cents here is that, use one storyboard to include multiple view controllers that are relevant in a same workflow (like Sunny said), and use xib for those small pieces that are repeatedly used in various places across the app. So for a complete app, you might end up with a few storyboards and each in turn has multiple related view controllers, plus some xibs if needed.

Comment: Multiple developer are not working one storyboard at a time because storyboard conflict when pull and push in Git.

Comment: Not necessarily, if two developers work on, say, two labels in two view controllers in one storyboard, you very likely won't get a conflict. There might be conflicts, but sometimes just in <document>

Answer (score 0):

Split up the Storyboard into several Storyboards. You can extract subviews into container views. Then you extract these into their own storyboards `-> Editor -> Refactor to Storyboard`.

Comment: Can  multiple developer work without conflict storyboard?